# How to check which user has added selected post?

Tags: django, post

I would like to know which user has added selected post. For example I have:

```
post = Posts.objects.all()[0]
```

this is my selected post and how can I get infos about the user which added the post?

Best regards,
nykon

PS. the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = u'Number')
```

Users have access to add number, so I have got a collection of numbers. I would like to know which user added given number.

Comment: Can you show the Posts model?  Or are you using something you installed with pip or easy_install?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a field that stores the user to your `Post` model. Something like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  number = models.IntegerField('Number')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Otherwise this information will not be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a field that stores the user, and set it when the record is created, you can't do this.

Comment: Aha, I see:) and how can I set the user when the record is created?